# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, avfoundation

I'm using a Swift file, a sub-class of `UIViewController` in a project which is basically built previously in Objective-C. The bridging-header file is added by Xcode. I'm getting following error:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate'

This is my VC:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ScanTargetAVFViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ScanTargetAVFViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

}
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried removing `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` from one of the objective-c file and it works now. However, I need to reference Swift code from my Objective-C files. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the MyProject-Swift.h file into MyObjectiveC.m rather than MyObjectiveC.h.  If there are Swift classes you need to reference in MyObjectiveC.h you can use the class directive.

```
@class MySwiftClass;
```

Comment: I'm already importing "MyProject-Swift.h" in my implementation file.